# iOS Today Extension notifying container app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

So I've got an app that allows users to create content which affects the app's badge number and generates local notifications.

I also want to have a widget that basically does most of what my app does. I've managed to get the data shared between the two and the widget showing the content fairly well but I can't get the app's badge number and local notifications to stay in sync with what's happening in the widget (without launching the container app).

Is there really no way for a widget to notify the app that it needs to do something without opening it, seems like a pretty legit use case, no?

Comment: Check out <notify.h>.  It's a very simple, system-wide notification system.

Comment: Is that a private API? It doesn't look like its for public use... Do you have any information on it?

Comment: I misread your question.  If the containing app is not running, there is no way for the extension to update its badge value or scheduled local notifications.  The closest you can get is for the extension to save its data to disk.  Then enable background fetch in the containing app, and when the containing app is woken up for background fetch update it's badge value and notifications.  Not exactly ideal because you don't have fine grain control over when (or if) your app will be woken up for background fetch.